# Compare data in Blade/View in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I'm grouping by date in the view. I want to compare it according to the incoming data and give the background color green if the data is larger than the data in the next row, red if it is smaller, and orange if it is equal. However, in the examples I examined, I could not compare the data coming with `data_get()` as I gave the table example below. Thanks a lot for your help.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Supplier</th>
            @foreach($dates as $date)
               <th>{{ $date->format('d.m.Y') }}</th>
            @endforeach
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach($suppliers as $supplier)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $supplier->name }}</td>
            @foreach($dates as $date)
                <td>
          {{ data_get($transactionsByDate, $date->toDateString()) }}</td>
            @endforeach
        </tr>
    @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use **data_get** you can use Carbon for the date comparison. Simply parse the dates (probably they are already a Carbon instance). Then compare them:

```
$firstDate = Carbon::parse(transactionsByDate);
$secondDate = Carbon::parse($date);
$first->greaterThan($second); // this will return true or false
```

Then you can use [these](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-comparison) comparison helpers.

Comment: I will compare according to the incoming total data, not by dates.